# Wildfly JavaEE 8 - Double initialization of Singleton EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, ejb-3.2

I'm building a JavaEE 8 application based on `Wildfly` archetype `ord.wildfly.archetype:wildfly-jakarta-ear-archetype:23.0.0.Final` and deplying it on `Wildfly 23.0.2.Final`.

This creates 4 projects

```
test
|---test-ear
|---test-ejb
|---test-web
```

in which `test-war` declares a dependency on `test-ejb` as a provided module.

However, if I define a `@Singleton @Startup` EJB in `test-ejb` like that

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Bootstrap {
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void postContruct() {
        System.out.println("********* BOOTSTRAP *********");
    }
    
}
```

it is initialized twice: one when the `test-ejb` is deployed, and the other when the `test-web` is deployed.

I didn't expect that given the `@Singleton` definition and the `provided` scope of the dependency.

I'm not doing anything in the projects configuration, I just added the singleton class as described above (I didn't even declared any dependency on logger libs as well to keep my modifications to the minimum)

What am I doing wrong?

---

### UPDATE: adding Manifest and descriptors

#### test-web

##### MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 15
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

##### beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

   <!-- This descriptor configures Context and Dependeny Injection.
        Actually, CDI 1.1 does not require this file. But the archetype contains it anyway to avoid deloyment errors for blank projects (WFLY-13306)   -->

</beans>
```

#### test-ear

##### MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 15
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

##### application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd" version="8">
  <description>This is the EAR POM file</description>
  <display-name>test-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>test-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>test-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/test-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

---

### UPDATE: LOGS

Diving into the logs, it looks like the problem is actually a double deployment rather than a dependency issue.

During a deploy (via Eclipse) I see a first chunk that reads:

```
...
18:52:15,803 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.ear
18:52:15,852 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.22.Final
18:13:46,577 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test-web.war
18:13:46,585 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test-ejb.jar
...
18:13:47,754 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) ********* BOOTSTRAP *********
18:13:47,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) ********* POST CONSTRUCT com.test.test.Bootstrap@65495f *********
...
```

then, I see a second chunk:

```
...
18:13:48,243 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.ear
18:13:48,265 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test-web.war
18:13:48,268 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test-ejb.jar
...
18:13:48,507 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) ********* BOOTSTRAP *********
18:13:48,507 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) ********* POST CONSTRUCT com.test.test.Bootstrap@1606409c *********
...
```

Is it correct that the EJB and WAR module are processed twice?

---

### UPDATE: Wildfly logs

Just tried increasing the log level of Wildfly itself. Going through the resulting file I don't see any exception. But I noticed this:

```
2021-06-22 18:44:59,357 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Deployment scan of [/home/xxxx/wildfly-23.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments] found update action [{
    "operation" => "composite",
    "address" => [],
    "steps" => [
        {
            "operation" => "add",
            "address" => [("deployment" => "togather-engine.ear")],
            "content" => [{
                "archive" => false,
                "path" => "deployments/XXXX.ear",
                "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir"
            }],
            "persistent" => false,
            "owner" => [
                ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
                ("scanner" => "default")
            ]
        },
        {
            "operation" => "deploy",
            "address" => [("deployment" => "XXXX.ear")],
            "owner" => [
                ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
                ("scanner" => "default")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "operation-headers" => {"rollback-on-runtime-failure" => false}
}]
```

and after a bit

```
2021-06-22 18:45:11,886 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment scan of [/home/xxxxx/wildfly-23.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments] found update action [{
    "operation" => "redeploy",
    "address" => [("deployment" => "XXXX.ear")],
    "owner" => [
        ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
        ("scanner" => "default")
    ]
}]
```

I verified the same behaviour on Wildfly 23 and 22.

Comment: Just as a first sanity test, have you checked the contents of test-war/WEB-INF/lib if the test-ejb.jar ends in there somehow? Another sanity check is the MANIFEST.MF of the war, is it declaring a dependency on the test-ejb? Oh, and please also check the jboss-specific deployment descriptors (if any) of the war (maybe the ear too, I do not remember if something in there might interfere)!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos hello, I've added the reource I could locate to the original post. They have not been modified, they're absolutely the ones created by the archetype out of the box.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I also made one more test to see if the Bootstrap class was instatiated twice, or was just the PostConstruct method that was called twice: the result is that the first option is the correct one: the Bootstrap class is instatiated twice, hence the PostConstruct method of each instancies are invoked.

Comment: Hi, did you check WEB-INF/lib of the war that is deployed - just in case the ejb jar found its way in there?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos hi. No, there is nothing in the deployed WAR libs (actually, since there is no explicit dependency declared on the WAR - just provided or test ones-, there is no lib folder at all)

Comment: Strange situation; at this point I would try to put Eclipse out of the equation: can you build the EAR from Maven and deploy it by hand to a **clean** installation of WildFly? I bet it will not deploy twice :) If so, try to clean the `deployments` folder of your WildFly, as well as the auxiliary folders (`data`, `tmp`), then deploy through Eclipse. Also take a look at `standalone.xml` near the end, does it contain any deployments? The web console can be helpful too. Finally, can you post the Eclipse setup you are using to deploy?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I also agree it is a problem with the Eclipse integration. Will try the test you proposed, but at the same time I'm fairly confident there is no actual double initialization of the Singleton bean. The server, for some reason, seems to be starting, stopping then starting the EAR again. This is not ideal, but can live with that in a dev environment.

Comment: If it is starting, stopping and starting again, you will see a message for stopping in the logs. Also, you can check the web console to see what is deployed, just to make sure.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I made the test you proposed. Actually, Wildfly keeps restarting the EAR. Also performed the test the other way around, removing all deployed apps from within Eclipse and starting the bare server: in this case it doesn't start twice.

Comment: If the server start correctly without the applicaiton, you may drop the ear to deployments folder, and have TRACE enabled. In that case you might see more information and can find the cause.
Even if in your dev environment the same behaviour is a mess in a prod instance as I would not expect it.
Another way to initialize duplicates is if you have added a xml declaration for the annotated classes.

Comment: @wfink I did as you suggested and increased Wildfly logs. I updated the question with the results.